# How to bulk extract personal certificates on Windows?

Tags: windows, certificate, export, user, bulk

We are upgrading computers to Win7 and I've found a computer with 300+ personal certificates and we need to save all of them. Is there a way to bulk export them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.wintools.com.au/certexport.php provide a tool: certmig

for example running:
certmig -e c:\temp\certs -all
puts all certificates as individual files in the above directory, with subdirectories of the actual source stores

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can find all the personal certificates under:

> %SystemDrive%\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto

so you can write a batch file which can copy these files. If you got access denied, you need to reassign the Administrator account the full access.